# Retrieve files and uploading .zip to s3 via Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-vpc

I want to filter my files in AWS S3 according to the incoming request, zip and upload them to s3 again and get a presigned url, fast.

I have following lambda function:

```
import { S3Client, ListObjectsV2Command, GetObjectCommand } from '@aws-sdk/client-s3';
import { Upload } from '@aws-sdk/lib-storage';
import { getSignedUrl } from '@aws-sdk/s3-request-presigner';
import archiver from 'archiver';
import { PassThrough } from 'stream';

export const handler = async (event) => {
  const bucketName = 'BUCKETNAME';
  const folderNames = ['MyFolder/']; 
  const targetZipKey = 'target.zip';

  try {
   
    const s3 = new S3Client({ region: 'us-east-2', });
    

    const archive = archiver('zip', { zlib: { level: 1 } });
    const passThroughStream = new PassThrough();
    archive.pipe(passThroughStream);

    const filePromises = [];
    console.log('files - start')
    for (const folderName of folderNames) {
      const listCommand = new ListObjectsV2Command({ Bucket: bucketName, Prefix: folderName });
      const { Contents } = await s3.send(listCommand);

      for (const file of Contents) {
        if (file.Key && !file.Key.endsWith('/')) {
          filePromises.push(
            s3.send(new GetObjectCommand({ Bucket: bucketName, Key: file.Key })).then((res) => {
              archive.append(res.Body, { name: file.Key.split('/').pop() });
            })
          );
        }
      }
    }
    console.log('files - finish')

    console.log('archive - start')
    await Promise.all(filePromises);
    console.log('archive - finish')

    archive.finalize();

    console.log('upload - start')
    const uploader = new Upload({
      client: s3,
      partSize: 10 * 1024 * 1024,
      queueSize: 10,
      params: {
        Bucket: bucketName,
        Key: targetZipKey,
        Body: passThroughStream,
      }
    });

    await uploader.done();
    console.log('upload - finish')

    const command = new GetObjectCommand({ Bucket: bucketName, Key: "Target.zip" });
    const signedUrl = await getSignedUrl(s3, command, { expiresIn: 18000 });

    return {
      statusCode: 200,
      body: signedUrl
    };
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(`An error occurred: ${error}`);
    return {
      statusCode: 500,
      body: `An error occurred: ${error.message}`,
    };
  }
};
```

The code I wrote works fine, but the upload process in aws takes too long. For example, for a 200mb file, an upload time of 15 seconds is required.

Logs:

[aws upload logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w0tZF.png)

However, I added a vpc and subnet to lambda. Can't I do this faster? I feel like these times are too high for aws.

[vpc and subnet config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tvbDG.png)

Comment: Make sure the Lambda function and S3 bucket are in the same region. Also, may be worth trying the same effective code on EC2 in that region. How does it compare?

Answer (score 1):

Increasing the [RAM and CPU](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/operatorguide/computing-power.html) size of your Lambda function may help.

> However, I added a vpc and subnet to lambda. Can't I do this faster?

I don't see how the VPC configuration would be relevant to the time the function takes to run.

I do however noticed you tagged this question with `amazon-efs`, although I don't see you mention it in the question itself. If you are writing the files to EFS at all during this process, that will **greatly** slow your function down. EFS is very slow. You should only be writing to the Lambda function's [ephemeral storage](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-function-common.html#configuration-ephemeral-storage) if you care about speed of disk I/O processes.

Comment: I removed the EFS tag, I think I added it by mistake.I have already increased the values you said, but for some reason it didn't have much effect. The current values are as follows ephemeral storage: 10000, memory: 3008. i can't increase memory more. They all seem to be at maximum value now.

Comment: Increasing the ephemeral storage doesn't increase speed, it just gives you more space to work with. If you don't need that space, then no reason to pay for more than you need. Increasing RAM/CPU beyond what your function actually maxes out as, is also pointless. You should check the log to see what it is actually using, and take the numbers down to that. If you aren't actually using EFS, there may not be much optimization to do here.

Comment: I would point out that the way you have the logging, both the download and the zipping of the files happens between "archive start" and "archive end". The files start/end just tracks the time it takes to list the files. Looking at your logs it appears most of the time is taken during the download from S3, and  upload back to S3. You might try adding an S3 VPC Endpoint to your VPC, some people claim that will help with the transfer speed. https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/storage/managing-amazon-s3-access-with-vpc-endpoints-and-s3-access-points/